# Insert php result from one page to input text from another page with js

Tags: php, text, input

Page1 : test.php (open in popup)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addFiles(aFiles) {
if ($('#addfiles').length==0) $('#addfiles').html;
for (var i=0;i<aFiles.length;i++)   $("#addfiles").append(""+aFiles[i].file+"");
                      }
</script>

<?php
$result = "<div id=\"addfiles\"></div>";    (everything works good here, i have only one result)
?>
```

Page2: results.php (main page , already open)

`<input type="texta" name="texta" id="texta" value="<? echo $result; ?>"/>` ( i need value="" to be auto updated with $result when $result have some result without refresh all page.)

Thanks

Edit:

```
function addFiles(aFiles) {
if ($('#addfiles').length==0) $('#addfiles').html;
for (var i=0;i<aFiles.length;i++) $("#addfiles").append(""+aFiles[0].file+"");
(window.opener.location = 'http://www.example.com/value='+aFiles[0].file+'');
self.close();   
}
```

Working great now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
if($result) {
    echo '<script language="JavaScript">window.opener.location = "http://example.com/?value='.$result.'");self.close();</script>';
}
?>
```

Then make the parent window get the value stored in 'value' via `$_GET['value']` and echo this into the 'value' attribute of the input field.

Comment: Thanks , but i need second page value="" to be updated , without refreshing all page, and some way how to get this $result , after the other page close.

Comment: Okay well if you don't want the whole page refreshing, you'll need to run an AJAX function that gets the value from a predetermined location once the child window has been closed.

Comment: Any exampe  please , thanks. I am newbie in AJAX. And i am stuck.

Comment: function addFiles(aFiles) {
if ($('#addfiles').length==0) $('#addfiles').html;
for (var i=0;i<aFiles.length;i++) $("#addfiles").append(""+aFiles[0].file+"");
(window.opener.location = 'http://www.example.com/value='+aFiles[0].file+'');
self.close(); 
}             Working great now. Thanks

Comment: No to worry, I'm glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, you are now writing a whole `<div>` into the `value="..."`